# Chrome DevTools: display function object's properties in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I console.log an object, I can expand it and view its properties and the whole chain of prototypes all the way up. When I console.log the function the click on it takes me to the function definition in the source code. I would like the same behaviour though: click on a function, expand it and see its prototype. How can I do that?

Comment: use firefox, or microsoft edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.dir` will handle what you are asking. Documentation available in the [Console API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference?hl=en#consoledirobject).

[image: console-dir-devtools]